# Help with Latex Gantt chart

Tags: gantt

I need a Gantt chart for my PhD proposal, and have found a simple example online. However, for 2019 I only need Q3 and Q4, but cannot see how to change this in the Latex code. Any help would be gratefully received.

Thank you in advance.

Here is the code I am using:

````
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{loopcntr}
\newcommand{\rpt}[2][1]{%
\forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\on}[1][1]{
\forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{&\cellcolor{gray}}
}
\newcommand{\off}[1][1]{
\forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{&}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.30\textwidth}*{12}{|p{0.03\textwidth}}|\hline}

\hline
\textbf{}&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{2019}
     &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{2020} 
     & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{2021} \\

\rpt[3]{& Q1& Q2 & Q3 & Q4}  \\
\hline  \on[1] \off[7] \on[4] \\
\hline
\on[3] \off[5] \on[4]   \\
\hline
\off[1] \on[2] \off[9]  \\
\hline
\off[2] \on[2] \off[8]   \\
\hline
\on[12] \off[0] \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
 ```
````

Comment: Please convert your code snippet into a complete minimal working example (MWE).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
    \usepackage{forloop}
    \newcounter{loopcntr}
    \newcommand{\rpt}[2][1]{%
        \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{#2}%
    }
    \newcommand{\on}[1][1]{
        \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{&\cellcolor{gray}}
    }
    \newcommand{\off}[1][1]{
        \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{&}
    }    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{|p{0.30\textwidth}*{12}{|p{0.03\textwidth}}|}
                \hline
                \textbf{}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{2019}
                     &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{2020} 
                     & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{2021} \\

                & Q3 & Q4 \rpt[2]{& Q1& Q2 & Q3 & Q4}  \\
                \hline  \on[1] \off[7] \on[2] \\
                \hline
                \on[3] \off[5] \on[2]   \\
                \hline
                \off[1] \on[2] \off[7]  \\
                \hline
                \off[2] \on[2] \off[6]   \\
                \hline
                \on[10] \off[0] \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

There is [a LaTeX package for drawing gantt plots using pgf](http://www.martin-kumm.de/wiki/doku.php?id=05Misc:A_LaTeX_package_for_gantt_plots) maybe you want to take look at this.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much!